# Relay setVariables function fail

Tags: javascript, graphql, relayjs, relay

First of all here is my fragment:

```js
initialVariables: {
    limit: 3,
  },
  fragments: {
    app: () => Relay.QL`
      fragment on App {
        id
        personnels(first: $limit) {
          pageInfo {
            hasNextPage
            hasPreviousPage
          }
          edges {
            cursor
            node {
              name
            }
          }
        }
      }
    `
   }
  }
```

initial read from server works fine, but when I am calling 
this.props.relay.setVariables, and trying to set limit variable I always get:

Server request for query `App_AppRelayQL` failed for the following reasons:

1. globalId is not defined
    node(id:$id_0) {
    ^^^

in the browser console. I think it might have something to do with the schema. But not sure what, so here is my schema:

```js
import {
  GraphQLSchema,
  GraphQLObjectType,
  GraphQLString,
  GraphQLInt,
  GraphQLList,
  GraphQLID,
  GraphQLNonNull
} from 'graphql';

import {
  nodeDefinitions,
  fromGlobalId,
  globalIdField,
  connectionDefinitions,
  connectionFromArray,
  connectionArgs,
  mutationWithClientMutationId
} from 'graphql-relay';

class App {};
class Personnel {};
let app = new App();
let Personnels = [];

(() => {
  let Jason = new Personnel();
  let John = new Personnel();

  Jason.name = 'Jason';
  Jason.id = 1;
  John.name = 'John';
  John.id = 2;

  personnels.push(YangGuoRong);
  personnels.push(DengLiFang);
})();


let {nodeInterface, nodeField} = nodeDefinitions(
  (gloablId) => {
    const {type} = fromGlobalId(globalId);

    switch(type) {
      case 'App':
        return app;
      default:
        return null;
    }
  },
  (obj) => {
    if (obj instanceof App) {
      return appType;
    } else if (obj instanceof Personnel) {
      return personnelType;
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }
);


let getPersonnel = (id) => personnels[id];
let getPersonnels = () => personnels;

let appType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'App',
  fields: () => ({
    id: globalIdField('App'),
    personnels: {
      type: personnelConnection.connectionType,
      args: connectionArgs,
      resolve: (_, args) => connectionFromArray(personnels, args)
    }
  }),
  interfaces: [nodeInterface]
});

let personnelType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'Personnel',
  fields: () => ({
    id: {
      type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLID),
      resolve: (obj) => obj.id
    },
    name: {type: GraphQLString},
  }),
});


let personnelConnection = connectionDefinitions({
  name: 'Personnel',
  nodeType: personnelType
});

new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'Query',
    fields: {
      node: nodeField,
      app: {
        type: appType,
        resolve: () => app
      },
    }
  }),
});

export default schema;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made a spelling mistake in your node definitions (you wrote gloablId instead of globalId in the second line). That's why globalId is not defined.

```
let {nodeInterface, nodeField} = nodeDefinitions(
  (gloablId) => {
    const {type} = fromGlobalId(globalId);

    switch(type) {
      case 'App':
        return app;
      default:
        return null;
    }
  },
  (obj) => {
    if (obj instanceof App) {
      return appType;
    } else if (obj instanceof Personnel) {
      return personnelType;
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }
);
```

When these errors appear I always try to pin down the bug by searching my code for the variable named in the error. That mostly helps

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot. Can't believe how careless I was. Many thanks. I think relay and graphql both have a lot of jargons you need to type exactly right, it would be great if they can make these APIs more flexible.

Comment: You're welcome. I also had a lot of situations where misspelling of some relay or graphql stuff caused errors. So I think you are right. But in this case globalId is just a variable name. You could also call it gloablId ;)

Comment: I bet if one can implement a kind of intellisense that sorts all these jargons out, a lot of people will use it.